# How to disable zooming ability on iOS for a particular element?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, zooming, pinchzoom

1) Go here on an iPhone/iPad: http://powellcreative.com/clients/Rotary/

I want, when the user zooms in on their device, for the menu bar to NOT zoom in and to stay where it's at and at it's current size.

Is this possible at all?